# Replace brackets and the content within the brackets in a variable

Tags: vimscript, substitute, replace

I'm currently stuck on this problem.
I want, in a vimscript, to replace a variable's brackets when they contain a certain pattern.

To say this differently, say I have a variable `foo = "[content] bar"` .
My purpose is to replace **[content]** with an empty string, which means that after the substitution we'll get: `foo = " bar"`.

The current solution I could find is:

```
let foo = substitute(foo, "\[\]", "") | let foo = substitute(foo, "content", "")
```

but couldn't manage to get it in one call.

Is there something I'm missing? Could this be done more easily?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

`:%s/\[[^]]*\]//g`

this somewhat cryptic regexp means to replace everything from start of bracket `[` followed by anything not a closing bracket `[^]]*` followed by the closing bracket `]` by nothing.

**Update**
Since you like to replace variable contents, let me show how to do that.
Suppose you have a variable *foo* (`:let foo="[content] bar"`), then you can do:

`let foo=substitute(foo, '\[[^]]*\]', '', 'g')`

The `echo '|'.foo.'|'` returns `| bar|` (note the leading space).

Make sure, to use **single quotation marks**, for double quotation marks you need to double the backslashes, as is explained in the help at `:h expr-quote`

Comment: Thanks Christian for the answer, I thought of using the `:substitute` command and indeed your suggestion is correct. However, I need this in a function, and applied to the `foo` var. Any thoughts?

Comment: the regex is still the same. You would simply use something like this: `let foo=substitute(foo, <regex>, '', 'g')`

Comment: I just tried, that doesn't replace anything :'(

Comment: @J.Doe you replaced `<regex>` by `'\[[^]]*\]'` in the `substitute()` call right?

Comment: @statox yes, that's what I did.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt , I'm sorry, I tried your update and that doesn't work either. I would have pasted a screen capture if I could. Anyway thanks.

Comment: what is your vim version?

Comment: I'm using Vim 7.4

Comment: exact version please?

Comment: also, please make sure to use **single quotation marks**

Comment: That's right, quotation marks. Thank you Christian. (that was irritating).

Comment: In double quotation marks, you need to double the backslashes. That is explained in the help at `:h expr-quote`